# How to read the XML in a text file and append it to RichTextBox

Tags: c#

I have the xml in a text file is

```
<text font='Bamini' color='#ffff80ff' font-size='8'>the </text>
<text font='Microsoft Sans Serif' color='#ff804000' font-size='8'>test </text>
<text font='Microsoft Sans Serif' color='#ff8000ff' font-size='8'>text </text>
<text font='Kal-72' color='#ff0080c0' font-size='8'>sample</text>
```

I would like to append the content of the text tag to the `RichTextBox`. i.e.,the content of the 1st text tag (`the`) will set the font type "Bamini",Co lor is "#ffff80ff" and the size is '8' like that the other tags also

Comment: Try to use some WYSIWYG editors. See this link http://ckeditor.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`RichTextBox.Rtf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf.aspx) to place `RTF` formatted text into the control for display or to extract the text of the control with the specified `RTF` formatting defined in the text of the control.

`RTF` encoding is different from `HTML`. You cannot do this straight away. I suggest `WebBrowser` control.

or try this ways from *codeproject*:

- [XHTML2RTF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/HTML/XHTML2RTF.aspx)
- [An-extended-RichTextBox-to-save-and-load-quot-HTML](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/htmlrichtextbox.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should use one of the two

1. Create a valid xml document file in which you could store your `text` elements ( your current format isn't a valid xml ). For more about xml operations in C# [Go here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx).
2. Create an `app.config` file and save / select values from that file. For more on this [Go here](http://geekswithblogs.net/MarkPearl/archive/2012/04/04/getting-app.config-to-be-configuration-specific-in-vs2010.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var textConfiguration = XDocument.Load(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Config.xml"));
        if (textConfiguration != null)
        {
            textConfiguration.Descendants("Configuration").Descendants("text").ToList().ForEach(text =>
            {
                font = text.Attribute("font").Value;
                color = text.Attribute("color").Value;
                fontsize = text.Attribute("font-size").Value;
                textToAppend = text.Value;

            });
        }
        richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.FromName(color);   
        richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(font, int.Parse(fontsize), FontStyle.Regular);
        richTextBox1.AppendText(textToAppend);
    }
```

The XML file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Configuration>
  <text font='Verdana' color='Green' font-size='8'>The Formatted Text</text>
</Configuration>
```

I Hope this will give you an idea.

If you have more then one text block, you can modify the code as below:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var textConfiguration = XDocument.Load(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Config.xml"));
        if (textConfiguration != null)
        {
            textConfiguration.Descendants("Configuration").Descendants("text").ToList().ForEach(text =>
            {
                font = text.Attribute("font").Value;
                color = text.Attribute("color").Value;
                fontsize = text.Attribute("font-size").Value;
                textToAppend = text.Value;
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.FromName(color);
                richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(font, int.Parse(fontsize), FontStyle.Regular);
                richTextBox1.AppendText(textToAppend);
            });
        }

    }
```

And the XML will be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Configuration>
  <text font='Verdana' color='Green' font-size='8'>The </text>
  <text font='Verdana' color='Red' font-size='8'>Formatted </text>
  <text font='Verdana' color='Blue' font-size='8'>Text</text>
</Configuration>
```

I have again modified code and now you can have Hex coloe code in your XML file.
Replace

```
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.FromName(color);
```

by

```
System.Drawing.Color col = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(color); 
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = col;
```

and replace

```
color='Green'
```

by

```
color='#ffff80ff'
```

Comment: I have more than one text how to implement it?

Comment: @Shankar: Refer the updated code. Please ACCEPT this answer if it satisfies your requirement.

Comment: yeah i did it Nirav i would like to remove the xml tag which have the innerText is empty?

Comment: Shankar, First of all what do you mean by "to remove xml tag"? If you have innerText empty (i.e. <text font='Verdana' color='Red' font-size='8'>Formatted </text> is replaced by <text font='Verdana' color='Red' font-size='8'> </text>) then above code will display formatted "The text" text in richTextBox1. And that is as equivalent to removal of text element.